# How To send Array or vector (has contact list ) from IdTCPServer to IdTCPClient (indy10)

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy10

1)
Now I am writing IM chat System i face some problem how to send vector that has information from the server to Client

2)
is any way to communicate between tow client ??

I Use CBC2010 - Indy10

Comment: Detail depends on what kind of information and data types do you have in your vector, are those simple data types, objects or records? Do your vector items have streaming capabilities? Do you have a ready routine to read/write each object/record to a stream? the entire vector?

Comment: 2) no way to make direct communication between tow pure clients, if  your client is lessening for incoming communication (not callback on a Chanel) then he is a server (not pure client)

Comment: @Najem
i mean by server that two client from it , i mean every client has thread ,,, is any way to make server send data from specific thread connection ...

Comment: I know you are - like me - not native English, but can you please run a spell checker, use less abbreviations and be a bit less dense in what you are asking? That way more people will actually understand what you are asking, and you will get more response.

Answer (score 1):

Basically communicating over TCP is about sending bytes from client to server, and receiving bytes on the  client from the server.

You either can give meaning to those bytes, or have something wrap that for you.

There are many possibilities and protocols to choose from.

On the foundation, you have either UDP (which is unreliable, but incurs almost no overhead, but very well suited for broadcasts) and TCP (which is more reliable, therefore has more overhead, but is easier to use).

A transport protocol that is often used on top of TCP is HTTP, especially since it is easy to get it through proxy servers.

On top of that you can do XML+SOAP or JSON+REST, which make translating from/to your underlying objects a lot easier.

All in all there are a truckload of options to choose from.

A simple start is the [Delphi chat example at delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa101105a.htm). That definitely should get you going.

Comment: thanks, at indy10 how to know that AContext belong to specific username and how to connect to other ...

Comment: @IYad: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Connecting to the other client is demonstrated in the Delphi chat room example I mentioned. What do you mean with `AContext belong to specific username`? You should probably add that to your question.